Utilizing bipartite network information in standard regression analysis
The gist of my somewhat general question is if there are some useful approaches to utilize information about relationships between individuals embedded in a bipartite network when the goal is a node-level analysis using standard regression models.
My main goal is to identify factors that explain whether an individual of a certain population gets vaccinated or not. I have two datasets:

1.) A dataset including distinct individuals with multiple individual-level variables (such as age, sex, vaccination-status, etc.).
2.) A dataset including information on which person visited which medical doctor.

Since there are no direct relationships between the doctors and no direct relationships between the individuals in this dataset, it is essentially a bipartite network. Using the information of the first dataset to predict vaccination status can be done easily using all sorts of models without problems. My problem is that I am unsure on how to use the second dataset. Here is what I thought of so far:

A) Aggregating information on doctor level (mean age of his patients, proportion of his patients vaccinated in the past etc.) and merging this to the first dataset is the simplest way I could think of. Since people may (and usually do) see multiple doctors at a given point in time there is, however, another level of aggregation needed. E.g. one has to take the average (or max, min etc.) of the doctor level variables to get just one value per person.
B) Creating the bipartite network, extracting node-level attributes (such as closeness, centrality etc.) and using these as predictors in a node-level regression.

Both options seem a little "hacky" to me, so I was wondering if there are more formal methods to combine the two kinds of informations I have. I would be very happy if someone had any ideas or could point me in the right direction literature wise. Any input is highly appreciated.
